# C# event removal syntax

Tags: c#, events, handler

I am confused by the syntax for removing event handlers in C#.

```
Something += new MyHandler(HandleSomething); // add
Something -= new MyHandler(HandleSomething); // remove
```

The "new" creates a new object on each line, so you add one object
and then ask it to remove a different object.

What is really going on under the covers that this can work?
It sure isn't obvious from the syntax.

Comment: Removal of an object searches the list of delegates for an object that matches the given object's target and method, and removes that.

Comment: you don't have to use new MyHandler, its just a wrapper for a delegate.

Comment: Answers to this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178725/how-to-unset-event have some discussion on the subject too.

Comment: Another closely related thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/99790/is-it-safe-to-add-delegates-to-events-with-keyword-new

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The += and the -= are syntax shortcuts for built-in internal methods named Add(), and Remove(), which add or remove a pointer to an internal linked list of delegates that the delegate has as a private field. When you run Remove, it starts at the head of the linked list and examines each delegate in the list one at a time until it finds one that is "equal" to the one you passed to the Remove() method.  ( using -= syntax)

Then, it removes that one from the linked list, and patches the linked list to retain it's connectivity...

In this context, the 'equals' method (for a delegate()) is overridden so that it only compares the target of the delegate, and the methodPtr, which will be the same even though you have created a new delegate to pass to Remove...

Answer (score 7):

The "new MyHandler" is actually redundant.  You can simply do

```
Something += HandleSomething; // add
Something -= HandleSomething; // remove
```

All events in C# are multicast delegates, so the += and -= syntax indicates that you are adding/removing a delegate to the list of delegates that will be called.

As for what's going on behind the scenes, the best explanation that I've found is [Jon Skeet's](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/events.html).

Comment: That's actually the same as the provided example, though the newer C# adds that for you.

Comment: You can leave the new'ing out, but if you let Visual Studio fill it in for you by typing: "Something +=" then <tab>, the autogenerated code will complete it similar to this: "Something +=new MyHandler(HandleSomething);" The OP is asking what goes on under the hood so that the new'ing way works.

Comment: Yeah I ended up being called away and didn't have enough time for a complete answer.  Both syntaxes are equivalent, the compiler infers the delegate and adds a new instance to the multicast list.  Even on removal, the "new EventHandler()" syntax works because it looks at the target & method signature and not a specific object ref.

Comment: Although this syntax shortcut does the same thing as the original syntax shortcut, at least this one makes good sense.  This can be used without causing confusion.  I like this new syntax much better.

Answer (score -1):

You can think of events as placeholder methods for the delegated logic that executes when the event is raised. A single event can have multiple subscribers (multi-casting), so the += and -= syntax is how a single event handler is attached or removed. Simply doing assignment would reset the event's subscriptions, which could cause unwanted side-effects.

EDIT: [this link](http://www.csharphelp.com/archives/archive253.html) explains more about eventing in C#

Comment: Why the down vote? This seems like a perfectly valid response.

Comment: Restating the OP's question: "Why we can += one new'ed object and -= an entirely different new'ed object and get the desired effect?" Josh E doesn't answer *why* we can attach 'a' and remove 'b' where 'a' and 'b' are different instances and still get what we want.

Comment: I had thought that by talking about subscription I covered that. Charles Bretana's answer covers this well so I'll refrain from editing my response